# Find a binary tree given only in-order traversal

Tags: binary-tree, inorder, preorder

I'm given an in-order traversal and need to find a binary tree. I referred my sites and most of them said it is not possible. However, i think a non-unique binary tree is possible. Can i find a binary tree using just given in-order traversal? If not, can i find a corresponding pre-order traversal from the given in-order traversal?

I tried to convert the in-order into pre-order by selecting the central node of in-order as the root but I'm not sure if its correct. Please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Given just the in-order traversal of the nodes, and no more information in the question, you can find *a* binary tree, but as you said, there won't be a unique solution (especially if the tree doesn't have to be balanced). As a result, you can again find *a* pre-order traversal.

As an example, if your in-order traversal is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, then even if the tree is balanced, there are multiple possibilities for the root node (namely, 4 or 5). If the tree *doesn't* have to be balanced, you could potentially pick any of these as the root node.

Here's an example of a non-balanced tree you could build after arbitrarily choosing 4 as the root node:

```
      4
     /  \
    3    6
   /    / \
  2    5   7
 /          \
1            8
```

Pre-order traversal for this tree would yield `4,3,2,1,6,5,7,8`. Again, if the only requirements are that you just find *a* binary tree, this is just as valid as setting 1 as the root node and making everything else a right node:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
       \
        5
         \
          6
           \
            7
             \
              8
```

The pre-order traversal for this tree would be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`. Since these trees both generate the same in-order traversal, but different pre-order traversals, there isn't guaranteed to be a single, unique tree or even a single, unique pre-order traversal for a given in-order traversal.

Comment: So how do i find the binary tree with given in-order? Can you please explain me? Thanks.

Comment: @Nisarg Patel Clarifying what Milo said above, there is nothing that stops you from having a "binary tree" that only uses left branches, or only uses right branches. Even in the case of a balanced binary tree, unless you have exactly 2^n-1 branches, you may have preferred left or right children for population.

Given all that, the pre-order is not unique, because it is dependent on the arrangement of nodes within the tree. If you build a binary tree using whatever arrangement you prefer, you can then build the pre-order list based on that particular tree.

Answer (score 0):

For more of one node there is no a unique binary search tree that contains the inorder traversal.

But if you want a tree, then just perform a random shuffle of inorder sequence and then insert the resulting randomized sequence in a binary search tree